# map-icons.js google is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I used map-icons from url:http://map-icons.com/ but map-icons.js, map-icons.css and 'fonts' file but I couldnt be successful. The error received is

> Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined at map-icons.js:42

map-icons.js

```
var inherits = function(childCtor, parentCtor) {
/** @constructor */
function tempCtor() {};
tempCtor.prototype = parentCtor.prototype;
childCtor.superClass_ = parentCtor.prototype;
childCtor.prototype = new tempCtor();
childCtor.prototype.constructor = childCtor;
};
function Marker(options){
google.maps.Marker.apply(this, arguments);if (options.map_icon_label) {
    this.MarkerLabel = new MarkerLabel({
        map: this.map,
        marker: this,
        text: options.map_icon_label
    });
    this.MarkerLabel.bindTo('position', this, 'position');
}
}
// Apply the inheritance
inherits(Marker, google.maps.Marker);
```

Line 42 at map-icons.js is "**inherits(Marker, google.maps.Marker);**"
I placed this without any change. What should I do? What should I change at map-icons.js file?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are including google maps **before** you include map-icons.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path-to-map-icons.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm sure. it points out "google.maps.marker" at map-icons.js so i think it's because of inheritence.